# Need help concatenating logged in user name in firebase database reference. Javascript

Tags: firebase

I am trying to store the form data in firebase realtime database. Currently I am using this,

```
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
var adRef = firebase.database().ref("post-ad/users/" + currentUser);
console.log(adRef);
var newAdRef = adRef.ref.push();
newAdRef.set({
        optCatEl: optCatEl,
        adTitleEl: adTitleEl,
        adDiscEl: adDiscEl,
        yourName: yourName,
        yourMobileEl: yourMobileEl,
        yourEmailidEl: yourEmailidEl,
    });
```

but I can't set the reference of `adRef` to `post-ad/users/currentUser`
when I check the log I get no feedback from it it's just empty.
I want to save the form info under current logged in user.

Comment: What are you getting in `console.log(currentUser)`?

Comment: @VicJordan I am getting the email of current logged in user